# Angular 8 getting the value of a BehaviorSubject returns null

Tags: angular

I am trying to setup this authentication solution:

https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/06/26/angular-8-basic-http-authentication-tutorial-example

In the **AuthenticationService** the constructor does this:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Token>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')));
    this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
}
```

which seems to be fine. When actually logging in, the **currentUserSubject** is invoked with the `next` method like this:

```
this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
```

The problem is, my **AuthGuard** invokes the method `currentUserValue` which is returning null unless I refresh my page.

That method is very simple and does this:

```
public get currentUserValue(): Token {
    return this.currentUserSubject.value;
}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?
My code is the same as the [code on the tutorial above](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/06/26/angular-8-basic-http-authentication-tutorial-example) but for some reason mine is not working.

---

Following @LppEdd answer, I tried to change my `canActivate` method to this:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> {
    return this.authenticationService.currentUserSubject.pipe(
       map(user => {
           console.log(user);
           let m = !!user;
           console.log(m);
           return m;
       }),
       catchError(() => of(this.router.createUrlTree(['login'], { queryParams: { retUrl: route.url} }))),
       take(1)
    );
}
```

When I log in and the `canActivate` is invoked, the first `console.log` is null and from my understanding it should not be. My authentication class now looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { Token } from './models/token';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {
    currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<Token>;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Token>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')));
    }

    login(username: string, password: string): Observable<void> {
        const params = new HttpParams({
            fromObject: {
                username,
                password,
                grant_type: 'password',
                scope: 'Sxp'
            }
        });

        const httpOptions = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Authorization': environment.authorization
            })
        };

        return this.http.post<Token>(`${environment.identityServerUrl}/connect/token`, params, httpOptions)
            .pipe(map(user => {
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                console.log(user);
                this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
            }));
    }

    logout(): void {
        // remove user from local storage to log user out
        localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
        this.currentUserSubject = undefined;
    }
}
```

---

The plot thickens. I decided to download the source files from the tutorial and then remove the fake backend provider and replace with my real api, including the authentication and it worked with no issues. So there is something wrong with my project.

As my project is new, I can only assume it's something to do with the lazy loaded routes. I am going to do some more investigation to see if I can fix it.

---

Well, I have no idea. I took the files from the tutorial and slowly built back my application. I have now got it back to the way it was and it all still works..... I am going to accept the answer given to me, because that is what I am using and it does work

Comment: Personally, I don't see the use of having an Observable there as the user information will always be available in localStorage. It's just adding an extra step which you don't really need. In  `get currentUserValue` you could just return the parsed localStorage item. That's how I normally deal with user data stored in storage.

Comment: I don't know why your implementation does not work (are you sure his code work?) but this code seems to be poorly designed ! `currentUserSubject` is already an observable and you should not access to its value by using `.Value`. You may find a better guide somewhere else.

Comment: @Florian in-fact, the `canActivate` method is able to use a native `Observable`, see my answer.

Comment: @LppEdd yes...? I know that, but OP seems to be trying to implement something he does not understand. The code he's trying to replicate uses bad practice, that's what I wanted to _highlight_

Comment: @Florian sure, you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CanActivate#canActivate` method has a return type specified as

```
Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree
```

That means you can actually leverage the asynchronous nature of Angular (with RxJS), and thus return your `currentUserSubject` `Observable`, e.g.

```
canActivate(...): Observable<boolean> {
   return this.currentUserSubject.pipe(
      filter(user => !!user), 
      mapTo(true),
      take(1)
   );
}
```

---

You can also set a time-out, and redirect the user to the *login* page.

```
canActivate(...): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> {
   return this.currentUserSubject.pipe(
      filter(user => !!user), 
      timeout(1000),
      mapTo(true),
      catchError(() => of(this.router.createUrlTree([...])),
      take(1)
   );
}
```

---

If you need to take into account other conditions, you can use

```
canActivate(...): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> {
   return this.currentUserSubject.pipe(
      timeout(1000),
      map(user => /* Your condition*/),
      catchError(() => of(this.router.createUrlTree([...])),
      take(1)
   );
}
```

---

The `take(1)` *pipable* operator lets the Guard know it can procede by completing, otherwise it will wait indefinitely the `Observable` completion.

Comment: This is great and seems to work with no issues. However, is there a way of checking if a user is logged in or not in the app.component? I have a menu that is only shown if the user is logged in

Comment: @r3plica I haven't really looked into the linked example, however normally the `currentUserSubject` would be accessible from a global Service. You could then inject that Service in your `WhateverComponent` and replicate (almost) the same logic.

Comment: what do I set currentUserSubject to, to return false? For example, when logging out?

Comment: @r3plica when logging out you should set it to `undefined`.

Comment: Not sure this is working then; it appears to always be true

Comment: @r3plica I don't understand what this has to do with the Guards. That means you're managing the Subject in an incorrect manner.
The initial value of the BehaviorSubject is never null or undefined, so you need to change the "filter" pipable operator behavior. This is outside my control (and knowledge)

Comment: @r3plica as of now the `filter(user => !!user)` will always be `true`, thus returning `true` from the Guard. You need simply to change it as per requirement.

Comment: @r3plica added a variation with a single `map` operator, which you can use to transform the `user` to a boolean value.

Comment: I have updated my question. I added your last bit (it was missing a bracket around the catchError method) and it's still not working

Comment: @r3plica I'm playing some video games now but the code you posted is wrong, as user is always true.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198265/discussion-between-lppedd-and-r3plica).

Comment: me too (dota2) how can user always be true, the first console.log is null

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public get currentUserValue(): Token {
    return this.currentUser;
}
```