# Angular 8 .next doesn't seem to work as expected

Tags: angular, auth-guard

I am trying to create a service that authenticates a user and stores the token in the localStorage.
I want other services (specifically the auth guard) to be able to access the current user, so I have set up the constructor of the authentication service like this:

```
currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<Token>;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Token>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')));
}
```

When a user logs in using a http POST request, if it's successful call the `next` method on the `currentSubject` like this:

```
return this.http.post<Token>(`${environment.identityServerUrl}/connect/token`, params, httpOptions)
    .pipe(map(user => {
        localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
        console.log(user);
        this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
    }));
```

The problem is, it doesn't seem to work. If I check my auth guard, it just sees the user as null. Only when I refresh is it populated (because of the authentication service constructor).

My auth guard looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { mapTo, take, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { AuthenticationService } from './authentication.service';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService
    ) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.authenticationService.currentUserSubject.pipe(
            filter(user => !!user), 
            mapTo(true),
            take(1)
        );
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

---

If I change my `canActivate` method to this:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean|UrlTree {
    var user = this.authenticationService.currentUserSubject.value;
    console.log(user);

    if (user) return true;

    this.router.navigate(["login"],{ queryParams: { retUrl: route.url} });
    return false;
}
```

It should work, but it just the console log shows `null` and so it just stays on the login page.

I saw that you can get `.value` from this article:
https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-rxjs-behaviorsubject-replaysubject-and-asyncsubject-8cc061f1cfc0

Comment: At a basic level, you are not actually returning anything from within the rxjs/operator map(). Therefore nothing will be returned the post to `/connect/token` and anything consuming it will receive `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subject `next()` method is used to send messages to an observable which are then sent to your angular components that are subscribed to that observable.

You have only created a subject but you have not created an observable that your guard can subscribe to.

```js
currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<Token>;
currentUser$ = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Token>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')));
}
```

By convention, observables have a `$` sign at the end. Now that we have a created an observable which receives your subject's messages, we can subscribe to it in the guard.

```js
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.authenticationService.currentUser$.subscribe(user => {
        console.log(user);
    });
}
```

I'm also not sure why you are using the `filter`, using `map` should be sufficient.

Comment: what does `!!user` mean?

Comment: @r3plica - check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript

Comment: `!!user` just gives you a boolean value. Basically if a `user` exists it will return true, else it will return false

Comment: I have updated my code so you just receive the `user` data in your subscribe. You can add whatever logic you want inside this subscribe method, for example, routing to another page.

Comment: @nash11 the code comes from https://stackoverflow.com/a/57594756/1392277 if you need context.